# Как получить аватар пользователя вконтакте?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Как получить аватар пользователя вконтакте?

Comment: читайте апи контакта, он возвращает все. хотя авОтар он не возвращает, а вот авАтар -- да.

Comment: я с ним уже запутался

Comment: уже исправил

Comment: что исправил?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[users.get](http://vk.com/dev/users.get)

Поля: photo, photo_medium, photo_big
Соответственно, для маленькой, средней и большой фотки.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте, [photos.get](http://vk.com/dev/photos.get)